# Can you put a conditional statement inside a here-doc?

Tags: ruby, heredoc

Can you put a conditional statement inside a here-doc?

IE:

```
sky = 1
str = <<EOF
The sky is #{if sky == 1 then blue else green end}
EOF
```

Thanks

Comment: You can do this, but it's good to look beyond the technical ability to do it and decide if it's good for code maintainability. I'd rather see the conditional test occur outside the here-doc, assigning to a variable, then embed the variable in the here-doc assignment. It might seem like a subtle difference in this example but helps keep the code better organized as a program grows, somewhat like separating logic from display in Rails or other MVC.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you can. (Did you try it?) HEREDOCs declared as you did act like a double-quoted string. If you happened to want the reverse, you would single-quote your HEREDOC indicator like so:

```
str = <<EOF
  #{ "this is interpolated Ruby code" }
EOF

str = <<'EOF'
  #{ This is literal text }
EOF
```

The "green" and "blue" in your example are wrong, unless you have methods or local variables with those names. You probably wanted either:

```
str = <<EOF
  The sky is #{if sky==1 then 'blue' else 'green' end}
EOF
```

...or the terser version:

```
str = <<EOF
  The sky is #{sky==1 ? :blue : :green}
end
```

As with all string interpolation, the result of each expression has `#to_s` called on it. As the string representation of a symbol is the same text, using symbols in interpolation like that saves one character when typing. I use it most often like:

```
cats = 13
str = "I have #{cats} cat#{:s if cats!=1}"
```

Comment: Awesome, works perfectly! Needed something similar to "I have #{cats} cat#{:s if cats!=1}". Thanks!

Comment: what if I have the :blue and :green in some variable? Say an array colors[0], colors[1] etc.. How will the heredoc change?

Comment: @VijayDev It's standard Ruby code wrapped in `#{...}`; try what you would expect to work and see.